# How to start ringing with default ringtone?

Tags: android

I need to start ringing with default system ringtone. Which must be a datasource for MediaPlayer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look this up

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(android.content.Context, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#getActualDefaultRingtoneUri%28android.content.Context,%20int%29)

You will have to pull out the actualDefaultRingtone and play the ringtone http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Ringtone.html

Comment: I have IllegalStateException in both cases after prepare()

Comment: If my post helped, please tick the question off :)